# repeat argument in itertools.product

Tags: python

I am trying to make different combination K and M. I use itertools.product. but repeat only takes integer. I would like to make a list of combinations with different lengths including 6,7,8,9,10,11. I made a list of required lengths and looped over this list but it gave only all combination of words with length of 11. here is some lines of my code:

```
wd = ['K','M']
k1 = [6,7,8,9,10,11]
for i in k1:
    motif = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(wd, repeat=i)]
```

how can I change this loop to get all combination of all lengths. 
so I would have a list like this (of course this is  small part of that)

```
results = ["KKKKKK", "KKKKKM", "KKKKMM", ... , "KKKKKKK", "KKKKKKM", "KKKKKMM", ........., "KKKKKKKKKKK", "KKKKKKKKKKKM", "MMMMMMMMMMM"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you overwrite `motif` on each iteration of cycle. You should do something like this:

```
wd = ['K','M']
k1 = [6,7,8,9,10,11]
motif = []
for i in k1:
    motif += [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(wd, repeat=i)]
```

Or this:

```
import itertools
wd = ['K','M']
k1 = [6,7,8,9,10,11]
motif = [''.join(p) for i in k1 for p in itertools.product(wd, repeat=i)]
```

Output:

```
['KKKKKK', 'KKKKKM', 'KKKKMK', ..., 'MMMMMMMMMMK', 'MMMMMMMMMMM']
```